# Render RazorPage with route parameter as string

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages, razorengine

I'm using the following code to render ASP.NET Core RazorPages as string:

```
public class RazorPageToStringRenderer : IRazorPageToStringRenderer
{
    private readonly IRazorViewEngine razorViewEngine;
    private readonly ITempDataProvider tempDataProvider;
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor httpContext;
    private readonly IActionContextAccessor actionContext;
    private readonly IRazorPageActivator activator;

    public RazorPageToStringRenderer(IRazorViewEngine razorViewEngine,
        ITempDataProvider tempDataProvider,
        IHttpContextAccessor httpContext,
        IActionContextAccessor actionContext,
        IRazorPageActivator activator)
    {
        this.razorViewEngine = razorViewEngine;
        this.tempDataProvider = tempDataProvider;
        this.httpContext = httpContext;
        this.actionContext = actionContext;
        this.activator = activator;
    }

    public async Task<string> RenderToStringAsync<T>(string pageName, T model) where T : PageModel
    {
        var context = new ActionContext(
            httpContext.HttpContext,
            httpContext.HttpContext.GetRouteData(),
            actionContext.ActionContext.ActionDescriptor
        );

        using (var sw = new StringWriter())
        {
            var result = razorViewEngine.GetPage(null, pageName);

            if (result.Page == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException($"The page {pageName} cannot be found.");

            var view = new RazorView(razorViewEngine,
                activator,
                new List<IRazorPage>(),
                result.Page,
                HtmlEncoder.Default,
                new DiagnosticListener("ViewRenderService"));

            var viewContext = new ViewContext(
                context,
                view,
                new ViewDataDictionary<T>(new EmptyModelMetadataProvider(), new ModelStateDictionary())
                {
                    Model = model
                },
                new TempDataDictionary(
                    httpContext.HttpContext,
                    tempDataProvider
                ),
                sw,
                new HtmlHelperOptions()
            );

            var page = (Page) result.Page;
            page.PageContext = new PageContext(actionContext.ActionContext)
            {
                ViewData = viewContext.ViewData
            };
            page.ViewContext = viewContext;

            activator.Activate(page, viewContext);
            await view.RenderAsync(viewContext);

            return sw.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

And that works fine when I call it like this:

```
private async Task SendEmail(int orderId)
    {
        emailModel = new InvoiceEmailModel{InvoiceNumber = orderId};
        string htmlBody = await razorPageToStringRenderer.RenderToStringAsync("/Areas/Email/Pages/InvoiceEmail.cshtml", emailModel);
        
        await emailSender.SendEmailAsync(UserEmail, $"Order #{orderId} Placed", htmlBody);
    }
```

However if I change my page to require a parameter by setting the first line in InvoiceEmail.cshtml to:

```
@page "{orderId:int?}"
```

Then I change the InvoiceEmailModel PageModel to have a new method called:

```
public IActionResult OnGet(int orderId)
```

It also works when I access it from the browser like this: localhost:5000/Email/InvoiceEmail?orderId=5. This only works when I comment out in Startup.cs MapControllers() and replace it with MapRazorPages() - both do not seem to work.

In any case, if I remove map razor pages, leave just map controllers and attempt to access the razor page I get a NullReferenceException in the Page InvoiceEmail.cshtml whenever I try to access the Model property and the OnGet method will not execute.

I have tried to set the ModelStateDictionary like this:

```
var modelState = new ModelStateDictionary();
modelState.SetModelValue("orderId", 5, "5");
```

And then use it in the ActionContext:

```
var context = new ActionContext(
            httpContext.HttpContext,
            httpContext.HttpContext.GetRouteData(),
            actionContext.ActionContext.ActionDescriptor,
            modelState
        );
```

But that did not change the output. Does anyone know how to specify the orderId page parameter and to get the OnGet method to also execute when I run it from code?

Comment: Hi I have done this before, can you add OrderId to your model that you pass to `RenderToStringAsync`

Comment: @DanielLoudon I have tried that but that doesn't get the OnGet method to be called in the InvoiceEmailModel PageModel and I just get a NullReferenceException in the view as the Model is null.

Comment: Why don't you just use **AddMvc** method it supports both razor and controller features.

Comment: @SalmanAkbar AddMvc calls AddControllersWithViews and AddRazorPages internally, I already have both these method calls in my ConfigureServices method but the problem is when I use MapControllers and MapRazorPages at the same time in the UseEndpoints method inside Configure. I have corrected by first post.